# How to combine the eclipse hot-key with control + s?

Tags: eclipse

I want to combine <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> with some eclipse hot-keys, like <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> etc, because it is convenient for my work.

Could you have some suggestions on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to format code and organize imports on save. Have a look at [Save Actions](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-save-actions.htm) which let you do exactly that.